# How to convert cucumber.api.Datable to List<MyClass> with more than 2 col in datatable

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

Gherkin Statement is :

```
And Instruments,Shareprice,Quantities to be added are
|name    |sal   |address|
|xyz     |100   |Greek  |
|abc     |200   |Italy  |
```

Step def is :

```
@Given("My emp details are $")
public void my_emp_details_are(DataTable arg1) throws Throwable {
    List<EMP> lstemp= arg1.asList(EMP.class);
}
```

Exception Generated:
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No such field datastructure.EMP.emps

EMP is Class with 3 fields:

Hey i am new to Java I have seen  asList() Documentation i didnt understand
public  List asList(Class itemType)

Type Parameters:
    T - the type of the list items
Parameters:
    itemType - the type of the list items

Comment: Got it Field name in Class were not matching with the DataTable Coloumn name thats why that exception came.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, you can get a List as the input parameter without further conversion.

```
@Given("My emp details are $") 
public void my_emp_details_are(List<EMP> lstemp) throws Throwable {}
```

if you EMP has the 3 fields (with setter methods) name, sal and address